# python use variable in Modbusclient

Tags: python, pymodbus3

I am having an issue with using a variable in a function.

```
ports = ["'/dev/ttyXRUSB0'","'/dev/ttyXRUSB1'"]
for item in ports:
  print len(ports)
  #port = item
  print item 
  client = ModbusClient(method = 'rtu', port = item, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0.2)
  print client
  client.connect()
```

I want to see client = ModbusClient(method = 'rtu', port = '/dev/ttyXRUSB0' baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0.2)

Where am i messing this up?

Comment: use  `ports = ['/dev/ttyXRUSB0','/dev/ttyXRUSB1']`

Comment: see [synchronous-client](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/synchronous-client.html)

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks man I knew i made a stupid error now it works